# Please help me calculating the limit of the function. Graphically it should go to 0, but how can I show it mathematically?

Tags: limits

What is $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}nx^n}$, for $0 < x < 1$?

Comment: ??? More details please. You want to compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} nx^n$? What is $x$? Are you trying to prove this limit is something (i.e. $\epsilon$ type proof), or just show it is something? What have you tried?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I want to show that it goes to 0

Comment: Are you allowed to use (or do you know of) L'Hopital's Rule. If so, see Heisenberg's hint below. Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0$ since $0<x<1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$, so the limit written below is indeed in indeterminate form.

Comment: Notice that $\frac{(n+1)x^{n+1}}{nx^n}=\frac{n+1}{n} x\to x$. Therefore, there is $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ it holds $$nx^n\le Nx^N\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^{n-N}$$

Comment: Yes and I have to differentiate it n times as each time it will come in a 0/0 form after shifting the coefficient of X to the numerator

Comment: You know the concept of an infinite series?

Comment: Yes, now that you mention it, yes the limit can be stated from power series

Comment: And you know the result which says that if $\sum a_n$ converges then $\lim a_n=0$? If you know it, that is precisely what is happening in your question.

Comment: Yes, i know that it's a necessary condition for convergence

Comment: Do I have to put details on how to use the ratio test?

Comment: No I can do it. Thank you sir . 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way of doing it is to to consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n,$$  where $|x|<1$. Its easy to check (Using the Ratio Test) that the series above converges. Hence,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}nx^n=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Use L'Hopital's Rule to $\frac{x^n}{\frac{1}{n}}$. However, you need $x<1$

Comment: You need $|x|<1$, as if $x=-2$ for instance, this limit does not converge.